# How to improve performance with F# idioms

Tags: performance, f#

I'm using [this course on Machine-Learning](http://work.caltech.edu/telecourse.html) to learn F# at the same time. I've done the following homework [exercise](http://work.caltech.edu/homework/hw2.pdf) which is the first exercise of the second week:

> Run a computer simulation for flipping 1,000 virtual fair coins. Flip
>   each coin independently 10 times. Focus on 3 coins as follows: **c1**
>   is the first coin flipped, **crand** is a coin chosen randomly from
>   the 1,000, and **cmin** is the coin which had the minimum frequency of
>   heads (pick the earlier one in case of a tie).
>
> Let **ν1** , **νrand**
>   , and **νmin** be the fraction of heads obtained for the 3 respective
>   coins out of the 10 tosses. Run the experiment 100,000 times in order
>   to get a full distribution of ν1 , νrand, and νmin (note that c rand
>   and c min will change from run to run).
>
> What is the average value of **νmin**?

I have produced the following code, which works fine and gives the correct answer:

```
let private rnd = System.Random()
let FlipCoin() = rnd.NextDouble() > 0.5
let FlipCoinNTimes N = List.init N (fun _ -> FlipCoin())
let FlipMCoinsNTimes M N = List.init M (fun _ -> FlipCoinNTimes N)

let ObtainFrequencyOfHeads tosses = 
    let heads = tosses |> List.filter (fun toss -> toss = true)
    float (List.length (heads)) / float (List.length (tosses))

let GetFirstRandMinHeadsFraction allCoinsLaunchs = 
    let first = ObtainFrequencyOfHeads(List.head (allCoinsLaunchs))
    let randomCoin = List.item (rnd.Next(List.length (allCoinsLaunchs))) allCoinsLaunchs
    let random = ObtainFrequencyOfHeads(randomCoin)

    let min = 
        allCoinsLaunchs
        |> List.map (fun coin -> ObtainFrequencyOfHeads coin)
        |> List.min
    (first, random, min)

module Exercice1 = 
    let GetResult() = 
        Seq.init 100000 (fun _ -> FlipMCoinsNTimes 1000 10)
        |> Seq.map (fun oneExperiment -> GetFirstRandMinHeadsFraction oneExperiment)
        |> Seq.map (fun (first, random, min) -> min)
        |> Seq.average
```

However, it takes roughly 4 minutes to run in my machine. I know that it is doing a lot of work, but I'm wondering if there are some modifications that could be made to optimize it.

As I'm trying lo learn F#, I'm asking for optimizations that use F# idioms, not to change the code to a C-style.

Feel free to suggest any kind of improvement, in style, good practices, etc.

**[UPDATE]**

I have written some code to compare the proposed solutions, it is accesible [here](https://github.com/Gua-naiko-che/FSharpPerformaceTest).

These are the results:

> Base - result: 0.037510, time elapsed: 00:00:55.1274883, improvement:
>   0.99 x
>
> Matthew Mcveigh - result: 0.037497, time elapsed: 00:00:15.1682052, improvement: 3.61 x
>
> Fyodor Soikin - result:0.037524, time elapsed: 00:01:29.7168787, improvement: 0.61 x
>
> GuyCoder - result: 0.037645, time elapsed: 00:00:02.0883482, improvement: **26.25 x**
>
> GuyCoder MathNet- result: 0.037666, time elapsed:
>   00:00:24.7596117, improvement: 2.21 x
>
> TheQuickBrownFox - result:
>   0.037494, time elapsed: 00:00:34.2831239, improvement: 1.60 x

The winner concerning the improvement in time is the GuyCoder, so I will accept his answer. However, I find that his code is more difficult to understand.

Comment: It's the 1st exercise from the 2nd week homework.

Comment: I have copied into my question the full formulation of the exercise! Anyway, here is the link: http://work.caltech.edu/homework/hw2.pdf

Comment: You asked for idiomatic F#, does that allow for the use of libraries commonly used with F# and that have functions for use with F# such as [MathNet Numerics](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/)? If not then I will probably pass on this question.

Comment: Sure! I would love to learn about it :)

Comment: `List.filter` and `List.map` allocate new lists, which can add up given the numbers involved. Try using equivalent `Seq.*` functions for producing intermediate sequences. E.g.: `let numberOfHeads = tosses |> Seq.filter id |> Seq.count`

Comment: One hint: `List.map |> List.min` could be replaced by `List.minBy`

Comment: @JohnPalmer: `|> List.map f |> List.min` would actually be equivalent to `|> List.minBy f |> f`, but it still avoids an intermediate list so it might help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running your code on my computer and timing I get:

```
seconds: 68.481918
result: 0.47570994
```

Running my code on my computer and timing I get:

```
seconds: 14.003861
vOne: 0.498963
vRnd: 0.499793
vMin: 0.037675
```

with vMin being closest to the correct answer of `b` being `0.01`

That is almost `5x` faster.

I did not tinker with each method and data structure to figure out why and what worked, I just used many decades of experience to guide me. Clearly not storing the intermediate values but just the results is a big improvement. Specifically `coinTest` just returns the number of heads which is an `int` and not a list of the results. Also instead of getting a random number for each coin flip but getting a random number for each coin and then using each part of that random number as a coin flip is advantageous. That saves `number of flips - 1` calls to a function. Also I avoided using `float` values until the very end; I don't consider that saving time on the CPU, but it did simplify the thought process of thinking only in `int` which allowed me to concentrate on other efficiencies. I know that may sound weird but the less I have to think about the better the answers I get. I also only ran `coinTest` when it was necessary, e.g. only the first coin, only the random coin, and looked for all tails as an exit condition.

```
namespace Workspace

module main =

    [<EntryPoint>]
    let main argv = 

        let rnd = System.Random()
        let randomPick (limit : int) : int = rnd.Next(limit)   // [0 .. limit) it's a Python habit

        let numberOfCoins = 1000
        let numberOfFlips = 10
        let numberOfExperiements = 100000

        let coinTest (numberOfFlips : int) : int =
            let rec countHeads (flips : int) bitIndex (headCount : int) : int =
                if bitIndex < 0 then headCount
                else countHeads (flips >>> 1) (bitIndex-1) (headCount + (flips &&& 0x01))
            countHeads (randomPick ((pown 2 numberOfFlips) - 1)) numberOfFlips 0

        let runExperiement (numberOfCoins : int) (numberOfFlips : int) : (int * int * int) =
            let (randomCoin : int) = randomPick numberOfCoins
            let rec testCoin coinIndex (cFirst, cRnd, cMin, cFirstDone, cRanDone, cMinDone) : (int * int * int) =
                if (coinIndex < numberOfCoins) then
                    if (not cFirstDone || not cRanDone || not cMinDone) then
                        if (cFirstDone && cMinDone && (coinIndex <> randomCoin)) then
                             testCoin (coinIndex+1) (cFirst, cRnd, cMin, cFirstDone, cRanDone, cMinDone)
                        else
                            let headsTotal = coinTest numberOfFlips 
                            let (cFirst, cRnd, cMin, cFirstDone, cRanDone, cMinDone) =
                                let cFirst = if coinIndex = 0 then headsTotal else cFirst
                                let cRnd = if coinIndex = randomCoin then headsTotal else cRnd
                                let cMin = if headsTotal < cMin then headsTotal else cMin
                                let cRanDone = if (coinIndex >= randomCoin) then true else cRanDone
                                let cMinDone = if (headsTotal = 0) then true else cMinDone
                                (cFirst, cRnd, cMin, true, cRanDone, cMinDone)
                            testCoin (coinIndex+1) (cFirst, cRnd, cMin, cFirstDone, cRanDone, cMinDone)
                    else
                        (cFirst, cRnd, cMin)
                else
                    (cFirst, cRnd, cMin)
            testCoin 0 (-1,-1,10, false, false, false)

        let runExperiements (numberOfExperiements : int) (numberOfCoins : int) ( numberOfFlips : int) =
            let rec accumateExperiements index aOne aRnd aMin : (int * int * int) =
                let (cOne,cRnd,cMin) = runExperiement numberOfCoins numberOfFlips
                if index > numberOfExperiements then (aOne, aRnd, aMin)
                else accumateExperiements (index + 1) (aOne + cOne) (aRnd + cRnd) (aMin + cMin)
            let (aOne, aRnd, aMin) = accumateExperiements 0 0 0 0
            let (vOne : double) = (double)(aOne) / (double)numberOfExperiements / (double)numberOfFlips
            let (vRnd : double) = (double)(aRnd) / (double)numberOfExperiements / (double)numberOfFlips
            let (vMin : double) = (double)(aMin) / (double)numberOfExperiements / (double)numberOfFlips
            (vOne, vRnd, vMin)

        let timeIt () = 
            let stopWatch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew()
            let (vOne, vRnd, vMin) = runExperiements numberOfExperiements numberOfCoins numberOfFlips
            stopWatch.Stop()
            printfn "seconds: %f" (stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds / 1000.0)
            printfn "vOne: %A" vOne
            printfn "vRnd: %A" vRnd
            printfn "vMin: %A" vMin

        timeIt ()

        printf "Press any key to exit: "
        System.Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
        printfn ""

        0 // return an integer exit code
```

========================================================================

This is just an intermediate answer because I inquired if the OP considered using MathNet Numerics idiomatic F# and the OP wanted to see what that looked like. After running his version and this first cut version on my machine the OP version is faster. OP: 75 secs, mine: 84 secs

```
namespace Workspace

open MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra

module main =

    [<EntryPoint>]
    let main argv = 

        let rnd = System.Random()
        let flipCoin() = 
            let head = rnd.NextDouble() > 0.5
            if head then 1.0 else 0.0

        let numberOfCoins = 1000
        let numberOfFlips = 10
        let numberOfExperiements = 100000
        let numberOfValues = 3

        let randomPick (limit : int) : int = rnd.Next(limit)   // [0 .. limit) it's a Python habit
        let headCount (m : Matrix<float>) (coinIndex : int) : int = 
            System.Convert.ToInt32((m.Row coinIndex).Sum())

        let minHeads (m : Matrix<float>) (numberOfCoins : int) (numberOfFlips : int) : int =
            let rec findMinHeads currentCoinIndex minHeadsCount minHeadsIndex =
                match currentCoinIndex,minHeadsCount with
                | -1,_ -> minHeadsCount
                | _,0 -> minHeadsCount  // Can't get less than zero so stop searching.
                | _ ->
                    let currentMinHeadCount = (headCount m currentCoinIndex)
                    let nextIndex = currentCoinIndex - 1
                    if currentMinHeadCount < minHeadsCount 
                    then findMinHeads nextIndex currentMinHeadCount currentCoinIndex
                    else findMinHeads nextIndex minHeadsCount minHeadsIndex
            findMinHeads (numberOfCoins - 1) numberOfFlips -1

        // Return the values for cOne, cRnd, and cMin as int values. 
        // Will do division on final sum of experiments instead of after each experiment.
        let runExperiement (numberOfCoins : int) (numberOfFlips : int) : (int * int * int) =        
            let (flips : Matrix<float>) = DenseMatrix.init numberOfCoins numberOfFlips (fun i j -> flipCoin())
            let cOne = headCount flips 0
            let cRnd = headCount flips (randomPick numberOfCoins)
            let cMin = minHeads flips numberOfCoins numberOfFlips
            (cOne,cRnd,cMin)

        let runExperiements (numberOfExperiements : int) (numberOfCoins : int) (numberOfFlips : int) : (int [] * int [] * int []) =
            let (cOneArray : int[]) = Array.create numberOfExperiements 0
            let (cRndArray : int[]) = Array.create numberOfExperiements 0
            let (cMinArray : int[]) = Array.create numberOfExperiements 0
            for i = 0 to (numberOfExperiements - 1) do
                let (cOne,cRnd,cMin) = runExperiement numberOfCoins numberOfFlips
                cOneArray.[i] <- cOne 
                cRndArray.[i] <- cRnd 
                cMinArray.[i] <- cMin 
            (cOneArray, cRndArray, cMinArray)

        let (cOneArray, cRndArray, cMinArray) = runExperiements numberOfExperiements numberOfCoins numberOfFlips
        let (vOne : double) = (double)(Array.sum cOneArray) / (double)numberOfExperiements / (double)numberOfFlips
        let (vRnd : double) = (double)(Array.sum cRndArray) / (double)numberOfExperiements / (double)numberOfFlips
        let (vMin : double) = (double)(Array.sum cMinArray) / (double)numberOfExperiements / (double)numberOfFlips

        printfn "vOne: %A" vOne
        printfn "vRnd: %A" vRnd
        printfn "vMin: %A" vMin
```

Halfway through the coding I realized I could do all of the calculations using just `int`, it was only the last calculations that generated the percentages that needed to be a `float` or `double` and even then that is only because the list of answers is a percentage; in theory the numbers can be compared as `int` to get the same understanding. If I use only `int` then I would have to create an `int` Matrix type and that is more work than I want to do. When I get time I will switch the MathNet Matrix to an F# [Array2D](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/collections.array2d-module-%5Bfsharp%5D) or something similar and check that. Note if you tag this with `MathNet` then the maintainer of `MathNet` might answer ([Christoph Rüegg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/30703/christoph-r%C3%BCegg))

I made an change to this method and it is faster by 5 seconds.

```
// faster
let minHeads (m : Matrix<float>) (numberOfCoins : int) (numberOfFlips : int) : int =
    let (mins : float[]) = m.FoldByRow((fun (x : float) y -> x + y), 0.0)
    let (minHead : float) = Array.min mins
    System.Convert.ToInt32(minHead)
```

Answer (score 6):

Allocating a large amount of lists up front is heavy work, the algorithm can be processed online e.g. via sequences or recursion. I transformed all the work into tail recursive functions for some raw speed (will be transformed into loops by the compiler)

*not guaranteed to be 100% correct, but hopefully gives you a gist of where I was going with it*:

```
let private rnd = System.Random()
let flipCoin () = rnd.NextDouble() > 0.5

let frequencyOfHeads flipsPerCoin = 
    let rec countHeads numHeads i =
        if i < flipsPerCoin then
            let isHead = flipCoin ()
            countHeads (if isHead then numHeads + 1 else numHeads) (i + 1)
        else
            float numHeads

    countHeads 0 0 / float flipsPerCoin

let getFirstRandMinHeadsFraction numCoins flipsPerCoin = 
    let randomCoinI = rnd.Next numCoins

    let rec run first random min i =
        if i < numCoins then
            let frequency = frequencyOfHeads flipsPerCoin
            let first = if i = 0 then frequency else first
            let random = if i = randomCoinI then frequency else random
            let min = if min > frequency then frequency else min

            run first random min (i + 1)
        else
            (first, random, min)

    run 0.0 0.0 System.Double.MaxValue 0

module Exercice1 = 
    let getResult () = 
        let iterations, numCoins, numFlips = 100000, 1000, 10

        let getMinFromExperiment () =
            let (_, _, min) = getFirstRandMinHeadsFraction numCoins numFlips
            min

        let rec sumMinFromExperiments i sumOfMin =
            if i < iterations then
                sumMinFromExperiments (i + 1) (sumOfMin + getMinFromExperiment ())
            else
                sumOfMin

        let sum = sumMinFromExperiments 0 0.0
        sum / float iterations
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried to find the smallest possible changes to your code to make it faster.

The biggest performance improvement I found was by changing the `ObtainFrequencyOfHeads` function so that it counts `true` values in the collection instead of creating an intermediate filtered collection and then counting that. I did this by using `fold`:

```
let ObtainFrequencyOfHeads tosses = 
    let heads = tosses |> List.fold (fun state t -> if t then state + 1 else state) 0
    float heads / float (List.length (tosses))
```

Another improvement came from changing all of the lists into arrays. This was as simple as replacing every instance of `List.` with `Array.` (including the new function above).

Some might say this is less functional, because it's using a mutable collection instead of an immutable one. However, we're not mutating any arrays, just using the fact that they are cheap to create, check the length of, and look up by index. We have removed a restriction on mutation but we are still not using mutation. It is certainly idiomatic F# to use arrays for performance if required.

With both of these changes I got almost a 2x performance improvement in FSI.